# whatsapp button sharing different url than actual

Tags: html, url, whatsapp

I have a working whatsapp `<a>` tag in this way:

```
<a class="whatsapp share-local-button
   data-action="share/whatsapp/share"
   target="_blank" href="whatsapp://send?text=link#withMark" >
   <i class="fa fa-whatsapp"></i>
</a>
```

This works, but what is in `href` is simply the shared text, not the url, which is the current....

I tried with

```
data-href="link#withMark"
```

But no different results...

How can I share my customized url **and not the current one?**

Comment: Looking at http://kriskbx.github.io/whatsapp-sharing/ it appears that `data-href` should work. Maybe it only accepts an actual URL? `link#withMark` would be invalid in this case

Comment: @CarlMarkham that seem to say in docs, but the the result I'm getting is **only** actual url, and can't figure out how to change it....

Comment: i don't understant what you intend for actual url...you have 2 urls? on of the site `www.expl.com` and the shared one `www.expl2.com#st`, and sharing on whatsapp with `href="whatsapp://send?text=www.expl2.com#st"` the text on whatsapp is `www.expl.com`?

Comment: @Emanuele yes, I have a site map with markers (https://www.ibeernalia.com), and I want to share the urls to open the desired marker in this way (https://www.ibeernalia.com/#bodegafermin)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding something like a bit of PHP if you are able to. if you want to keep it clean html then just ignore this.

in php u define the link u want to set in a variable, then just add `<?php $yourvariable ?>` to the `whatsapp://send?text= INSERT HERE`

Comment: is coded in javascript, not a problem to add PHP lines, but url is already used from variable to fill the html in the marker.

Comment: Ah ok well it was a possibility to use so ye. I tried :)

Answer (score 0):

Add a JavaScript code as I did to dynamically add the link.

Also it is reusable and can be used in any page.

Here, we set the `href` of the element having `class=whatsapp` to it's `href+` the site link.

Try running the code

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('whatsapp')[0].href+=window.self.location;
```

```html
<a class="whatsapp share-local-button
   data-action="share/whatsapp/share"
   target="_blank" href="whatsapp://send?text=">
   <i class="fa fa-whatsapp">whatsapp</i>
</a>
```

Comment: Whith this all buttons will have same (and wrong) URL. Aside of this, which will be the difference? When I create buttons dinamically via javascript I know what URL must contain, but it does not open the written after text but actual one....